# Fail to start application after deploy to tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, vps

I have a linux vps, i had installed tomcat 9 and everything are working fine. But after i had deployed a Java Spring MVC war file to tomcat (let's call it example.war), when i pressed "start", it showed a message: `FAIL - Application at context path [/example] could not be started` (i used the tomcat manager). My Java Spring project used to be deployed by tomcat 7 plugin on my home computer.

Comment: This is a "too general" question. So many things can go wrong, I suggest to see the logs of tomcat and check whether there are relevant ERRORS there. Another option is to check the logs of the application itself (in case it uses the logging system) - maybe its an "application level" issue.

Comment: the log says : " java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter", i meet this problem when trying to run this project on tomcat 9 in my home pc too.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
```

Basically means that there is no class available in the classpath of your application.
This class is a part of jar `spring-web-<YOUR_VERSION_OF_SPRING>.jar`

So first open up your WAR file and check whether its in WEB-INF/lib folder.
If it isn't the changes are that it was deployed into the lib folder of tomcat 7 (that works) and in tomcat 9 both on your linux machine and development PC there is no jar like this.

Comment: i checked and it isn't there, how can i fix this? Plus, i tried to run project with "tomcat v7.0 server at local host" in my home pc and it thrown the same error, but the project worked fine with the tomcat7-maven-plugin. I really don't understand why

Comment: The fix is simple: add spring-web into the list of maven dependencies (or whatever build system you use and re-build). Then again, check `WEB-INF/lib` the jar should be there. Try to run on tomcat 7, tomcat 9, etc.

Comment: i had already had a spring web dependency, i think that is not a solution